# Not able to install visualization_common stack

Tags: ros, stack, ogre

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm trying to install the visualization_common stack again (removed the old one as the ogre had problems with rviz) using [individual stack install](http://www.ros.org/wiki/electric/Installation/Ubuntu)

```
sudo apt-get install ros-electric-visualization-common
```

But my system is telling me this:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
ros-electric-visualization-common is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

How do I let the system know that there is no such stack anymore and do a fresh installation?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/12672/not-able-to-install-visualization_common-stack/) by [weiin](https://answers.ros.org/users/1505/weiin/) on ROS Answers with karma: 2268 on 2012-01-17

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

`apt-get install --reinstall ros-electric-visualization-common`

Generally, you should remove packages through the package manager (apt-get remove ...) rather than delete the files. Otherwise, you get into cases like this, where the package manager is out of sync with the system.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2012-01-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [weiin](https://answers.ros.org/users/1505/weiin/) on 2012-01-17**:
Thank you! It worked (for rviz as well).